# Printing two arrays in csv side by side

Tags: java, arrays, csv, for-loop, foreach

I have two `String` arrays: sentence and score.

I want to create a .csv file in which the first column is made of elements from sentence and the second column is made of elements from score.

I'm having trouble understanding where the problem in my code is and how to fix it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class GeneraCsv {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] sentence = {"sentence 1", "sentence 2", "sentence 3"};
        String[] score = {"score 1", "score", "score 3"};
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/Gonzalo/Desktop/test.csv"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("sentence");
        sb.append(';');
        sb.append("score");
        sb.append('\n');
        for(String a: sentence) {
            sb.append(a);
            sb.append(";");
            for(String b: score) {
                sb.append(b);
                sb.append('\n');
                break;
            }
        }
        pw.write(sb.toString());
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("done!");
    }
}
```

My code generates this:

```
sentence; score
sentence 1; score 1
sentence 2; score 1
sentence 3; score 1
```

The first column is fine, the second is not.

The output I want should be like:

```
sentence; score
sentence 1; score 1
sentence 2; score 2
sentence 3; score 3
```

I'm sure there is a problem in the loops somewhere.

How to fix?

Comment: If you want to have `sentence 2; score 2` in output, you need to change your initialisation, because there is only `score`, not `score 2`.

Comment: @RO_engineer seems like that is a typo , it should be `score 1", "score 2", "score 3"` and NoobNw0 it you just want to print score and sentence then let me know that can be done in far optimized way

Comment: @RO_engineer nice eyes there

Comment: *FYI:* CSV means **Comma**-Separated-Values. `;` is not a *comma*.

Comment: indeed, it was a typo, I'm sorry!

@Andreas you're right, but for me comma does not work as a separator while semicolon does. I think it's a regional setting of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue

You are always using first input of score inside inner loop

```
for(String a: sentence) { 
            sb.append(a); // this will iterate the sentence array in sequential order
            sb.append(";");

            for(String b: score) {
              // this will always pick score 1 because there will be only one iteration due to break
                sb.append(b);
                sb.append('\n');
                break; // stop the loop after first iteration
            }
        }
```

so use this

1.) Iterate the array according to array length using index

2.) Access the data using index and append it your `StringBuilder`

```
    for(int i=0;i <score.length;i++) {

        sb.append(sentence[i]);
        sb.append(";");

        sb.append(score[i]);
        sb.append('\n');                
        //System.out.print(sb.toString()); to print values 
        //sb =new StringBuilder();
    }
    pw.write(sb.toString());
    pw.close();
```

Note : Replace both loops with this single loop

Output :

```
sentence 1;score 1    
sentence 2;score    
sentence 3;score 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer of @PavneetSingh is the short term solution to you problem and will work.

But the better approach would be to change your design away from 2 separate arrays to a single array in conjunction with a custom class. (This is why we call Java an *object oriented language* btw...)

This solution would look like this:

```
class SentenceScore{
  private final Sting sentence;
  private final int score;
  SentenceScore(Sting sentence, int score){
    this.sentence  =  sentence;
    this.score  =  score;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "sentence: "+sentence+"; score: "+score;
  }
}

for(SentenceScore sentenceScore : sentenceScores){
    sb.append(a); 
    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Comment: This is interesting too, with some use of method overriding. I'll give it a shot soon